# How I can add element in array of map in firebase SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase

I have data in Firebase and I make request an check if requestdate == my date I want to add time to this requestdate

```
  "booking_days": [
    {
      "date": "__Timestamp__2023-11-05T05:11:54.301Z",
      "day_off": false,
      "time": [
        "11:30"
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "__Timestamp__2023-11-04T05:20:17.640Z",
      "day_off": false,
      "time": [
        "14:30"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

I try  to do like this code

```
   func setBookingTimeForExistingDay(userId: String, bookingDays: BookingDay, existingDay: Date) async throws {
        guard let bookingDay = try? encoder.encode(bookingDays) else {
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
        let orderBookingTime: [String : Any] = [DBPortfolioModel.CodingKeys.bookingDays.rawValue : FieldValue.arrayUnion([bookingDay])]

       
        try await portfolioUserDocument(userId: userId).setData(orderBookingTime, mergeFields: ["\(existingDay)"])
    }
```

I want get result like this

```
 "booking_days": [
    {
      "date": "__Timestamp__2023-11-05T05:11:54.301Z",
      "day_off": false,
      "time": [
        "11:30",
        "12:30"
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "__Timestamp__2023-11-04T05:20:17.640Z",
      "day_off": false,
      "time": [
        "14:30"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: where is your code for `if requestdate == my date` that you mention? Note that a `Date` is just a point in time [Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date).

Comment: I do it in another code
and I get result 
my question is how I can call inside booking_days array object with "date": "MyDate()" and append to this object in field "time" string value